# DAX - Date calculations based on pivot filters

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I just learned about PowerPivot last week, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around how this all works.

I have a table of contracts with start and end dates. I have a second lookup with month (indices) and month end dates. (1) The DAX calculates the number of days in the contract. (2) Based on the `Month` filtered, it calculates the number of days between the contract start and the `MonthDate`.

Contracts:

```
Account   Start       End        ContractDays  DevDays
359ABC    1/10/2019   1/10/2020
948EDI    2/5/2019    2/5/2020
```

Lookup Table:

```
Month    MonthDate
1        1/31/2019
2        2/28/2019
3        3/31/2019
```

I want the DAX to calculate `ContractDays` and `DevDays` in the Contracts table above.

**1.** Calculate `ContractDays`

I think I got this one. I added a column called `ContractDays` with the formula `=[End]-[Start]`. Easy...

**2.** Calculate `DevDays`

If the user filters to `Month` = 2, then I want to calculate the number of days between the contract start and 2/28/2019. So the resulting pivot would show:

```
Account   Start       End        ContractDays  DevDays
359ABC    1/10/2019   1/10/2020  365           49
948EDI    2/5/2019    2/5/2020   365           0
```

I'm calculating a measure called `UseEvalDate = lookupvalue(lku[MonthDate], lku[Month], filters(lku[Month]))`. This determines the `MonthDate` to use.

Then I added a column in Contracts: `DevDays = [UseEvalDate] - [Start]`. This is erroring out... saying "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected." What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the trick is to use measures for all of these things. My final measure for the number of days between the MonthDay and Contract start is: `DevDays = sumx(contract, datediff(contract[Start], [UseEvalDate], day))`.